# collectionViewCell imageView proportionally

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uicollectionview

I have a CollectionViewCell where i want to add a imageView. This imageView should be set to exact size, so it is proportional without cutting, something out of the image by resizing. How can i do this? Do i need to do it programmatically or can it be done in autolayout?

The example of this is the images on this picture below. where they have the exaact height as the images?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add constraint at runtime programmatically.

By calculating image's height and width and than add constraint for it's height and width.

Constraint for it's X and Y should be set before this

```
[imageView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:[myView(==width)]"
                                                               options:0
                                                               metrics:nil
                                                views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(imageView)]];
[imageView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[myView(==height)]"
                                                               options:0
                                                               metrics:nil
                                                views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(imageView)]];
```

Comment: what is myView in this case?

Comment: and do i add this to my UICollectionViewCell in `init`

Comment: myView is your imageView itself, you can replace it with imageView. You can add it in init or where you get the image itself.